# starting a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat and package as an executable JAR file.

I started my application on Ubuntu 14.04 LTSwith

```
 java -DAPPKEY=oracle -Dspring.profiles.active=oracle -jar licence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But after some hours the application was down, the process was not running anymore. Was this a proper way to start the application ? 
I have no clue why the process shutdown

Comment: It is a correct way to start the application. Read the Spring Boot docs about logging, make sure that it's sending its logs somewhere you can read. Next time it terminates, it should leave a log showing why.

Comment: BTW if you're starting it in an interactive shell, you may need `nohup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to run your application as a service take a look at the installation guide in the spring boot doc:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

As you can see if you are using init.d services you can link the jar inside the init.d directory.

The fat jar contains the init scripts:

```
sudo ln -s /var/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp
```